# How do I manipulate the contents typed/pasted into a textfield and have that result saved to the db in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I would like to store the youtube embed link version of youtube URL's in my db. I have a helper that helps convert the users pasted link into the embed version.

Anyway before saving I'd like to convert it then pass the converted value over to the model for it to be saved. I've created a method in my controller that I use to pass the link param into the helper method that does the conversion.

Anyway this has no effect. The orignal link pasted into the text box gets saved. I've tried doing this in the model with before_save and self.link but it doesn't work either. Below is my current code.

**Form:**

```
= form_for @micropost, :remote => true do |f|
  = f.text_field :link, :class => "addLinkField"
  = f.submit
```

**Helper for converting pasted link:**

```
module OgpObjectsHelper
  def video_embed(video_url)
    if video_url[/(https?):\/\/(www.)?(youtube\.com\/watch\?v=|youtu\.be\|youtube\.com\/watch\?feature=player_embedded&v=)([A-Za-z0-9_-]*)(\&\S+)?(\S)*/]youtube_id = $4
      "http://www.youtube.com/embed/#{ youtube_id }"
  end
end
```

**Controller:**

```
class MicropostsController < ApplicationController
  include OgpObjectsHelper

  before_filter :convert_video_link

  def create
    @micropost = current_user.microposts.build(params[:micropost])
        respond_to do |format|
            if @micropost.save
              format.html { render :partial => '/users/partials/micropost'} 
            end
        end
  end

  def convert_video_link
    video_embed(params[:micropost][:link])
  end

end
```

I would appreciate a best approach solution thanks.

Kind regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put it in your Micropost model and do not forget to validate cos if no match to youtube format, link will now be nil

```
# micropost.rb 
include OgpObjectsHelper

before_validate :convert_video_link

protected 
def convert_video_link
  self.link = video_embed(link)
end
```

Comment: I have client side validation for this. I would prefer this in model also. I might give it ago but I don't like to include helpers in models.

Comment: just don't call it a helper. it still belongs there.

Comment: I ended up going with this... It just felt right in the model as it was being manipulated just before save. Also having it in my controller caused issues with some other code unless I applied the before filter to create only. That pushed me to put it in the model in the end.

Comment: What does protected do? I'll need to read up on that. I've only ever used private.

Answer (score 1):

In the code you have above, you need to modify the `convert_video_link` method to read:

> params[:micropost][:link] = video_embed(params[:micropost][:link])

Since you are still creating the record from the `param` values. The method as it stands does not alter those parameters.

Comment: How could  I miss that! Gosh! Thanks for your help. It's working fine now. Explains why I was getting "nil" error before.

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies in your helper. You're trying to set the `link` attribute to the 4th backreference in your regex but not actually assigning the value. The filter just returns a link but doesn't set any attribute on the model to that link. My suggestion would be to move this into a before_save on your model. The following untested code should do it.

```
class Micropost

before_save :convert_video_url

def convert_video_url
  url = self.link
  youtube_id = url.scan(/(https?):\/\/(www.)?(youtube\.com\/watch\?v=|youtu\.be\|youtube\.com\/watch\?feature=player_embedded&v=)([A-Za-z0-9_-]*)(\&\S+)?(\S)*/)[0][3]
  self.link = "http://www.youtube.com/embed/#{ youtube_id }"
end
```

Note, the regex will break if YouTube change the format of their URLs.

Robin